# Does Rectangle.getX() return the upper corner or the center?

Tags: java, awt, rectangles, coordinate

Say I have a `java.awt.Rectangle` set up as:

```
x - - - - - - -
| - - - - - - - |
| - - - - - - - |
| - - - - - - - |
| - - - y - - - |
| - - - - - - - |
| - - - - - - - |
- - - - - - - - -
```

Does `getX()` return the x-coordinate of `x` or `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getX()` returns the **top-left** x-coordinate.

The source says it all:

**Looking at the `Rectangle(x, y, width, height)` constructor:**

```
public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
   this.x = x;
   ...
}
```

**The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for the above says:**

> Constructs a new Rectangle whose upper-left corner is specified as (x,y)

**Looking at `getX()`:**

```
public double getX() {
   return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getX() will return the upper corner. The information for a Rectangle in Java is x,y,width,height so these are the values you can set and retrieve natively.